# Microsoft SQL Express localhost connection

Tags: sql-server

I've been following up a tutorial (sql server 2008) and I'm a bit in a doubt.
It seems like it names my localhost with my Windows username by default and I need a confirmation about this because if I try to connect to the server name either  : (local), . , 127.0.0.1 I'll get an error.

[image]

Here's the error when I try to directly specify localhost
[image]

I am a bit confused, sorry for the ambiguous question. It's just that I've been following up a tutorial but on sql server 2008.

Comment: Yes. You're very confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` - you need to specify the instance name.

To use just (local), the machine name or IP without an instance name you would need to have installed SQL Express as the default instance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so basically my PC's name is equal with (local) and . . I know it was a lame question but I've just started learning SQL Express. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, as is your IP address and your loopback address (127.0.0.1). It's not lame, everyone starts somewhere and if you got that from a tutorial then it would be confusing. Actually according to this it might be a bug in the install - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958778

Comment: thanks again, I've worked waay to much with EasyPHP and mySQL admin panel, which were pretty easy to setup and stuff.